# Erro na hora de executar o programa trava.Lista circular(Resolvido) Porém ainda estou com dúvida

Tags: c, lista

Estou com um erro que só aparece durante a execução do programa. 
Gostaria que alguém que tenha o conhecimento do porque disso ocorrer, possa me explicar.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct TNoDeCaractere
{
char caractere;
struct TNoDeCaractere *proximo;
};

 struct TNoDeCaractere* inicio;

void insere(char valor){
struct TNoDeCaractere *p, *np;

//Se a lista está vazia, cria um nó e faz "inicio"apontar para ele.
if(inicio == NULL){

np=malloc(sizeof(struct TNoDeCaractere));
(*np).caractere= valor;
(*np).proximo =inicio;
inicio=np;

}else{//Caso contrário, ou seja, se a lista não está vazia...
p=malloc(sizeof(struct TNoDeCaractere));
p=inicio;
//varre toda a lista,
while((*p).proximo !=inicio){
p=(*p).proximo;
}printf("Teste");
//Cria novo nó
np=malloc(sizeof(struct TNoDeCaractere));
(*np).caractere=valor;
(*np).proximo=inicio;
// e liga a lista existente ao novo nó.
(*p).proximo=np;
}
}
void imprimir(){
struct TNoDeCaractere *p;
p=inicio;
while((*p).proximo !=NULL){
   printf("Valor: %d \n",(*p).proximo);
    p=(*p).proximo;
}
}
 void remover(char valor)
{
struct TNoDeCaractere *pAnt, *p;
//Verifica se a partir do segundo nó, há nó a ser retirado.
pAnt=inicio;
p=(*inicio).proximo;
while(p!=inicio)
    {
        if((*p).caractere == valor)
        {

            (*pAnt).proximo=(*p).proximo;free(p);
            p=(*pAnt).proximo;
        }else{
            pAnt=(*pAnt).proximo;
            p=(*p).proximo;
            }
    }//Testa se a lista estácom o valor aser retirado no primeiro nó
    if((*inicio).caractere == valor)
    {

        p=(*inicio).proximo;
        free(inicio);
        inicio=p;
    }

}




int main(){

inicio=NULL;


insere("a");

insere("c");
insere("b");


imprimir();

remover('b');

imprimir();
}
```

obs: Coloquei um "printf("Teste")" afinal do loop(Na função insere)que é onde o programa para.

Resolvi como fazer o código após algumas tentativas e manipulações nas posições de ponteiros. No entanto o motivo que me fazia errar eu não sei. Apenas manipulei o código todo para tentar fazer ele funcionar. Vou postar agora o código correto.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

   struct TNoDeCaractere
   {
   char caractere;
   struct TNoDeCaractere *proximo;
    };

    struct TNoDeCaractere *inicio;

    void insere(char valor){
    struct TNoDeCaractere *p, *np;
   //Se a lista está vazia, cria um nó e faz "inicio"apontar para ele.
   if(inicio == NULL){
   np=malloc(sizeof(struct TNoDeCaractere));
  (*np).caractere= valor;
  (*np).proximo =np;
  inicio=np;

  }else{//Caso contrário, ou seja, se a lista não está vazia...
  p=inicio;
  //varre toda a lista,
  while((*p).proximo !=inicio){
  p=(*p).proximo;}
 //Cria novo nó e insere no final.
 np=malloc(sizeof(struct TNoDeCaractere));
 (*np).caractere=valor;
 (*np).proximo=inicio;
 // e liga a lista existente ao novo nó.
(*p).proximo=np;
}
}
void imprimir(){
 struct TNoDeCaractere *p;
 p=inicio;
  while((*p).proximo !=inicio){
    printf("Valor: %c \n",(*p).caractere);
     p=(*p).proximo;
 }
 printf("Valor: %c \n",(*p).caractere);// Linha para imprimir ultima letra.
 }
void remover(char valor)
 {
  struct TNoDeCaractere *pAnt, *p;
   //Verifica se a partir do segundo nó, há nó a ser retirado.
  pAnt=inicio;
  p=(*inicio).proximo;
  while(p!=inicio)
    {
        if((*p).caractere == valor)
        {

            (*pAnt).proximo=(*p).proximo;free(p);
            p=(*pAnt).proximo;
        }else{
            pAnt=(*pAnt).proximo;
            p=(*p).proximo;
            }
    }//Testa se a lista estácom o valor aser retirado no primeiro nó
    if((*inicio).caractere == valor)
    {

        p=(*inicio).proximo;
        free(inicio);
        inicio=p;
       }

}




int main(){

inicio=NULL;


insere('G');insere('a');insere('b');
insere('r');insere('i');insere('e');insere('l');


imprimir();

remover('b');

imprimir();
}
```

Comment: qual é o erro ? o que deveria acontecer, e o que está acontecendo ? você precisa explicar claramente...

Comment: Então amigo o erro é exatamente o nome do "post". Por favor leia de novo para ver que não tem um "nome" como erros clássicos de compilação. Ele tem um erro durante a execução que é a fase em que o programa está funcionando na máquina. Porém o programa não me responde nada. Apenas trava e para de funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

struct TNoDeCaractere
{
   char caractere;
   struct TNoDeCaractere *proximo;
};

struct TNoDeCaractere *inicio = NULL;

void insere(char valor)
{
   //boas praticas
   //sempre inicialize as variavies que sera utilizadas
   struct TNoDeCaractere *p = NULL, *np = NULL;
   //Se a lista está vazia, cria um nó e faz "inicio"apontar para ele.
   if (inicio == NULL)
   {
      //boas praticas
      //quando alocar memoria sempre teste para ver se não ocorreu erro
      if ((np = (struct TNoDeCaractere *) malloc(sizeof(struct TNoDeCaractere))) == NULL)
      {
         printf("Falha de alocaçao de memoria\n");
      }
      else
      {
         np->caractere = valor;
         np->proximo = np;
         inicio = np;
      }
   }
   else
   {//Caso contrário, ou seja, se a lista não está vazia...
      p = inicio;
      //varre toda a lista,
      while (p->proximo != inicio)
      {
         p = p->proximo;
      }
      //Cria novo nó e insere no final.
      //boas praticas
      //quando alocar memoria sempre teste para ver se não ocorreu erro
      if ((np = (struct TNoDeCaractere *) malloc(sizeof(struct TNoDeCaractere))) == NULL)
      {
         printf("Falha de alocaçao de memoria\n");
      }
      else
      {
         np->caractere = valor;
         np->proximo = inicio;
         // e liga a lista existente ao novo nó.
         p->proximo = np;
      }
   }
}
void imprimir()
{
   struct TNoDeCaractere *p = inicio;
   //p = inicio;
   while (p->proximo != inicio)
   {
      printf("Valor: %c \n", p->caractere);
      p = p->proximo;
   }
   printf("Valor: %c \n", p->caractere);// Linha para imprimir ultima letra.
}
void remover(char valor)
{
   struct TNoDeCaractere *pAnt = inicio;
   struct TNoDeCaractere * p = inicio->proximo;
   //Verifica se a partir do segundo nó, há nó a ser retirado.
   //
   while (p != inicio)
   {
      if (p->caractere == valor)
      {
         pAnt->proximo = p->proximo;
         free(p);
         p = pAnt->proximo;
      }
      else
      {
         pAnt = pAnt->proximo;
         p = p->proximo;
      }
   }//Testa se a lista estácom o valor aser retirado no primeiro nó
   if (inicio->caractere == valor)
   {
      p = inicio->proximo;
      free(inicio);
      inicio = p;
   }
}
//não há necessidade de derefencia pointeiros quando você ira utilizalos diretamente
//isto pode confundir o compildador ao indexar um endereço de memoria
//este pode ser o problema que seu programa esta entrando em parafuso.
int main()
{
   struct TNoDeCaractere * top = NULL;
   struct TNoDeCaractere * next = NULL;
   insere('G'); insere('a'); insere('b');
   insere('r'); insere('i'); insere('e'); insere('l');
   imprimir();
   remover('b');
   imprimir();
   //
   //sempre libere toda a memoria utilizada
   //pois se não fizer isto e rodar o programa varias vezes pode ocorreu falta de memoria no sistema
   //ou outros problemas, pois o sistema pensa que esta memoria ainda esta em uso
   top = inicio;
   next = inicio->proximo;
   while (next != inicio)
   {
      top->proximo = next->proximo;
      free(next);
      next = top->proximo;
   }
   free(inicio);
}